# Have I failed the PSU “paperclip test?”

Tags: power-supply

My computer stopped functioning today so I decided to see if it was the PSU. My PSU is a [Cooler Master: V750](http://www.coolermaster.com/powersupply/modular/v750s/).

I performed the [“paperclip test”](http://support.antec.com/support/solutions/articles/1000015319-is-my-power-supply-dead-the-paperclip-test) on my PSU and the fan turned on, However it only stayed on for approx 3/4 a second and then turned off, Followed by a beautiful click noise. Does this mean I passed or failed the test?

Comment: What's the paperclip test? What prompted you to do it? And what results did you expect from it? Please [edit] your question to add some more information.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Everything you need to know is in my question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Short the green wire on the 20/24-pin ATX connector to any of the black wire. The PSU should turn on. Note that not every PSU will switch on the internal fan when this is done; a fan or other load may need to be connected to the PSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paperclip test emulates how the motherboard would turn on the PSU. If doing so doesn't turn on the PSU then it is likely that your PSU no longer works.

Disconnect the PSU from everything (but mains) and ideally connect a multimeter across a power lead and check if there is a voltage. Presuming you don't have a multimeter, plug in a hard drive (not an SSD!) and see if it spins up when you perform the paperclip test again (if you hold the hard drive you should feel it spin up)

Comment: The hard drive did not spin up. Also i have a Molex, Lighting system, This would not turn on either.

Comment: Remember to always just see if a fresh CMOS battery on the motherboard
will solve the "PSU won't start" problem. Also with many newer PSUs, the
unit will "play dead" with just the paperclip test without a real
load/motherboard connected.

Answer (score 4):

Its worth understanding what the paperclip test is, and what *exactly* it does.

A paperclip test is a good way to work out if your PSU is *completely* dead, as opposed to another issue. It is no replacement for a proper PSU tester.

Essentially the only question it answers is "Does the sense cable pick up that its grounded?"

From what you say, yes you failed it. If you *passed* it still dosen't mean that your PSU is *completely* healthy. You'd want to check each 'rail' to see if its the correct voltage, which a proper PSU tester would do automatically.